# Amazon SQS messages

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

For Amazon SQS - If the number of requests a cron job can make in a given window is exceeded by the number of messages received in SQS, how would you ensure all messages are processed in that window?

Comment: Hi! Could you please edit your Question to provide more information so that we can provide a good Answer? For example, can you explain what your cron job does -- does it push messages *into* the queue, or take messages *out of* the queue? What do you mean by "processed in that window"? Are you saying that you have a cron job that pulls one message out of the queue, and you are concerned that there might be too many messages in the queue, compared to messages processed? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Standard Queues can hold upto 120,000 Messages and Fifo queues can hold upto 20,000  Messages. These messages can be set to be retained upto 14days which is pretty much.

So Even If the number of requests a cron job can make in a given window is exceeded by the number of messages received in SQS:

- All the Incoming messages are still stored in the queue.
- The Cron Job/Jobs just takes the first message from the queue and processes it.
- Make sure you know and set the Visibity time out while reading from the queue and delete the message from the queue after it is processes. Otherwise, the cron job keeps processing the same message again and again.
- Refer other AWS SQS features for better processing And utilizing.

To ensure all messages are processed in that window, As I mentioned You just need run the CRON Job with proper setting.

If you have a Delivery deadline which we will be having in most of the cases, Configure the environment to be Autoscaled.

We can even configure scale-in and scale-out based on SQS message.

Happy to Help.. :)